# Get all routes from NgRx router-store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-router-store

Is there some built-in selector to get all app routes from NgRx router-store?
Or does NgRx router-store even include the router routes at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ngrx/router-store`, does not store all routes from an app.

It has:

- [actions that dispatch on navigation](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store/actions)
- [selectors to select data from the **current** route](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store/selectors)
- [serializers to decide what goes into the store](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store/configuration)

https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store

> Bindings to connect the Angular Router with Store. During each router navigation cycle, multiple actions are dispatched that allow you to listen for changes in the router's state. You can then select data from the state of the router to provide additional information to your application.

Comment: Ok, cool thanks! In order to get all routes of the app, it might be needed to be asked from Angular router itself?